# How to plot transition among multiple groups in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn, data-visualization

I want to plot a transition between multiple groups in python. Say I have three groups A, B and C at a given datetime x. Now at datetime y > x I want to visualize what % of elements of A transitioned into group B, what % to C. Similarly for B and C. I can for now assume that there are a fixed number of elements. Also can I extend this to multiple dates like x < y < z and visualize the changes ?

A sample dataframe of my usecase can be generated using this code

```
elements = [f'e{i}' for i in range(10)]
x = pd.DataFrame({'element': elements, 'group': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], size=10), 'date': pd.to_datetime('2021-04-01')})
y = pd.DataFrame({'element': elements, 'group': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], size=10), 'date': pd.to_datetime('2021-04-10')})
df = x.append(y)
```

Now from the above dataframe I want to visualize for the 2 dates how did the transition from groups A, B and C happened.

My main issue is I don't know what plot to use in python to visualize this, any leads will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach to get what you need, i.e. shift from one date to another:

```
# pivot the data so dates become columns
s = df.pivot(index='element', columns='date', values='group')
```

which gives `s` as:

```
date    2021-04-01 2021-04-10
element                      
e0               A          A
e1               A          C
e2               B          B
e3               B          B
e4               C          C
e5               A          C
e6               B          B
e7               C          A
e8               C          A
e9               C          A
```

Next,

```
# compare the two consecutive dates
pairwise = pd.get_dummies(s.iloc[:, 1]).T @ pd.get_dummies(s.iloc[:,0])
```

which gives you `pairwise` as:

```
   A  B  C
A  1  0  3
B  0  3  0
C  2  0  1
```

That means, e.g. first column says that there are 3 `A`'s on the first date, one stays `A` and 2 change to `C` on the second date. Finally, you can easily compute the percentage with

```
pairwise / pairwise.sum()
```

Output, which you can use something like `sns.heatmap` to visualize:

```
          A    B     C
A  0.333333  0.0  0.75
B  0.000000  1.0  0.00
C  0.666667  0.0  0.25
```

**Note** as to the extended question, you would have a series of these matrices for each pair `(day1, day2), (day2, day3),...`. It's up to you to decide how to visualize them.

Comment: @NikhilMishra if you saw the answer before I edited it: There was an update in definition of `pairwise`.

Comment: yes observed it. still wondering if there's a better way to show transition. I am more concerned about the visualization part, how to best demostrate it